# How to compress a single file in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gzip

How to compress a single file inside a `Copy` task without having extra headache with creating and compressing temporary files manually?

For example, when you build a `deb` package, you should compress some files with `gzip`:

```gradle
task buildDeb(type: Deb, dependsOn: ['jar']) {

    // ...

    from (file('packaging/deb-package/manpage')) {

        into '/usr/share/man/man1'
        //rename(/.*/, deploymentName + '.1.gz')
        rename(/.*/, deploymentName + '.1')

        filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            'TITLE': appTitle,
            // ...
        ])

        // XXX
        //compressItWithGzip();

    }

    // ...

}
```

The built-in `ant` tools support only text filtering via the `Reader` interface. So, how to do something like compressing (or, in general, any binary manipulation)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ant.gzip(src: <source>, zipfile: <target>)
```

in you task, catch the [docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pack.html).

Also, maybe instead of putting too much logic in a single task, define a set of tasks (one would be responsible for this gzipping) and tie them with dependencies.

Comment: So, there are no way to place it in the copy spec? I really wanted to avoid this additional preparation task (expensive copying to a tmp dir, or excluding manually handled gzipped files, or some other kind of annoyances) just for some gzipping, while token replacing and renaming can be easily defined in the copy spec.

Comment: @DávidHorváth, to be honest, I don't see the way right now. Maybe adding an action will help you somehow (`doFirst` in this case).